# I don't understand why i get the orphaned error near default in my code

Tags: java, switch-statement

```
switch(countryCode){
    case "GB":
        validLength = 22;
        break;
    case "GR":
        validLength = 27;
        break;
    break;
    case "SA":
        validLength = 24;
        break;
    case "CH":
    
        validLength = 21;
        break;
    case "TR":
    
        validLength = 26;
        break;
    }
    break;
    default:
    System.out.println("Unknown country code: " + iban.substring(0,2));
    return -1;
```

I have a small bit of code here and keep getting the orphaned error near default and I can't seem to understand or fix it

Answer (score 2):

The `default` cause should be inside the curly braces alongside the other `case`s.

```
switch (countryCode) {
    case "GB":
        validLength = 22;
        break;
    case "GR":
        validLength = 27;
        break;
    case "SA":
        validLength = 24;
        break;
    case "CH":
        validLength = 21;
        break;
    case "TR":
        validLength = 26;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Unknown country code: " + iban.substring(0,2));
        return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

default has to be inside the brackets of your switch statement, because it is the "default-case".
The "break;" statement right before your default-statement makes also no sense - break is used to leave the switch-statement code and continue with the next statement outside the brackets of the switch.